# Remove back button Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch 2 to build an application. I am initially loading the navigation view in the view port and then pushing the login view. After login it takes to the main page. Here I have a back button, which when clicked goes back to the login page. How can I prevent this? I googled a lot but could not find an effective answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt would be to add the login view directly to the Ext.Viewport instead of pushing into the navigationView. Then, once the login process is completed, you have to destroy the login view so you can add the navigationView to the Viewport.

This way the login view wont be in the navigationView stack.

Hope it helps-